# how to write formula for displaying year range in crystal report?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

hi i am new to crystal report and c# application Actuvally i want to dispaly year range  like given like this 
2012-2013 2013-2014 2014-2015...so on
i have done by displaying year wise like this
2012      2013    2014      2014..

foir this i use a formula like this
toText (year(CurrentDate)) + "-" + toText (year(CurrentDate) + 1) but when i was save and close it shows error like this
 selection part must be  in a boleean variable like this type of error is comming so plz help me to solve this error
 thanks advance

Answer (score 2):

`toText (CurrentDate,"yyyy") + "-" + toText(DateAdd("yyyy",1,CurrentDate),"yyyy")`